# why angular-material css file didn't load until you refresh page?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, webpack, angular-material

I am using angular 1.6 with Webpack, I have a angular-material.css as stylesheet, and also I have edit-app.html should use this angular-material.css.

If I go from my homepage -> edit-app.html, the angular-material.css didn't get loaded, until I hit the refresh page button on my browser.

So I am researching how did the webpack load the css files, I do check that in the webpack.config.js, however, mine is different:

```
import makeWebpackConfig from 'angular-portal-dependencies/src/webpack/make-webpack-config.js';
export default makeWebpackConfig(__dirname, {});
```

How to solve this issue, let the angular-material.css file loaded, when the project init, or manually add that css file to the edit-app.html page.

Comment: are you using a css loader and requiring it in the controller for that view?

Comment: @alphapilgrim  in that makeWebpackConfig function inside node_modules folder, yes

Comment: id suggest adding your webpack.config